# Aligning two scans to make a solid

Tags: mesh

how do I align two scans to make a solid, please ? I have a scan of the top and a scan of the bottom of an object. Now I want to align them using reference points, to make a solid stl file that I can print. thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add a picture of the imported top and bottom's mesh

Comment: It is a lot better and more reliable to build scan as a solid using photogrammetry software from beginning. Aligning scans meshes can become cumbersome and often inprecise task since scan of only top or only bottom will always have slight deviations from the shape it would have if it was just cut in 2 parts. Note also that you can't align scans using references points, those make sense only to photogrammetry software which Blender isn't

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do this before with a boxy shaped object but it was a couple of years ago. I think what I did was join both of those meshes as a single object and then use the remesh modifier on that.

I'm just for the life of me trying to remember how I fixed the messy geometry between the scans XD